# How to find urls in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I have simple attributed string:

```
let string = NSAttributedString(string: "hello https://www.stackoverflow.com")
```

When I display that string I would like to see:

```
hello URL
```

where `URL` is clickable link and opens `https://www.stackoverflow.com`.

The link is not hardcoded, at the time when I replace it, I don't know how much, (if any) links exist there.

**EDIT:**

Look at the question and compare to the one marked as duplicated. It is NOT DUPLICATED. Please review it wisely and smart.

Comment: Your use of `?title=` as the delimiter to separate the link display text and the URL is ambiguous. `?title=myprivateblog` could be a part of the URL, couldn't it? You can't tell. Also, when does the link display text stop? At the first whitespace you encounter? The next URL found? It can't always continue all the way to the end of the string, can it?

Comment: First of all, thank you for your time and reply. Yes, it stops at the first whitespace. I know it is not the best way to create title for links... but it was not my business decision... But for now, any detected url can be replaced with "URL" for example.

Comment: You need to explain the logic, is it always `?title=` (which seems here to be a URL Query Item)? if yes, I'd say to use a Regex, (or NSDataDector), to detect the link `https://www.stackoverflow.com?title=myprivateblog`, and remove the `?=title=MyTitle` part from the URL and put it as such.

Comment: @Larme I changed the qustion. Actually it doesnt matter (for now) what title I replace the link with. But it should be detected and replaced. Explaining the logic, I mean "if there is a title query parameter then display value for that parameter as a title for link" NSDataDetector and regex seems good. I didnt know that... Let me try.

Comment: Regarding the request for reopening: commentary on duplicates in questions is OK, but it needs to explain _why_ it is different. Saying it is not a duplicate, or that readers need to review it more wisely, is insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
let linkDetector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
let str = "hello at https://www.stackoverflow.com or http://google.com ?"

let attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)

let matches = linkDetector.matches(in: attrStr.string, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.string.utf16.count))

matches.reversed().forEach { aMatch in //Use `reversed()` to avoid range issues
    let linkRange = aMatch.range
    let link = (attrStr.string as NSString).substring(with: linkRange) //Or use Range
    //Here, you could modify the "link", and compute if needed myURLTitle, like URL(string: link)?.host ?? "myURLTitle"
    let replacement = NSAttributedString(string: "myURLTitle", attributes: [.link: link])
    attrStr.replaceCharacters(in: linkRange, with: replacement)
}

print(attrStr)
```